# Get image from sdcard and send it to next activity

Tags: android

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (requestCode == RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE && resultCode == RESULT_OK && null != data) {
            Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
            String[] filePathColumn = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };

            Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage,
                    filePathColumn, null, null, null);
            cursor.moveToFirst();

            int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
            String picturePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
            cursor.close();

            ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView10);
            imageView.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath));
        }
}
```

I use this code to load image from sd card. The problem is when I click on add button, it shows the gallery of my cellphone but when I select the image it shows me force close error...
I show this image in my ListView and how can I resize the image? Maybe my image is too large, that's why it didnt fit in my ListView.

LogCat:

```
06-01 04:51:09.793: W/KeyCharacterMap(5401): No keyboard for id 0
06-01 04:51:09.793: W/KeyCharacterMap(5401): Using default keymap: /system/usr/keychars/qwerty.kcm.bin
06-01 04:51:19.933: D/dalvikvm(5401): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 6030 objects / 254136 bytes in 79ms
06-01 04:51:21.273: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(5401): showStatusIcon on inactive InputConnection
06-01 04:51:22.813: D/dalvikvm(5401): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 797 objects / 47568 bytes in 45ms
06-01 04:51:22.884: D/AndroidRuntime(5401): Shutting down VM
06-01 04:51:22.884: W/dalvikvm(5401): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d800)
06-01 04:51:22.903: E/AndroidRuntime(5401): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-01 04:51:22.903: E/AndroidRuntime(5401): java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=1, result=-1, data=Intent { dat=content://media/external/images/media/1 }} to activity {com.example.fatwallet/com.example.fatwallet.Create_adds_Activity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
06-01 04:51:22.903: E/AndroidRuntime(5401):     at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3515)
06-01 04:51:22.903: E/AndroidRuntime(5401):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3557)
06-01 04:51:22.903: E/AndroidRuntime(5401):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2800(ActivityThread.java:125)
06-01 04:51:22.903: E/AndroidRuntime(5401):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2063)
06-01 04:51:22.903: E/AndroidRuntime(5401):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
06-01 04:51:22.903: E/AndroidRuntime(5401):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
06-01 04:51:22.903: E/AndroidRuntime(5401):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
06-01 04:51:22.903: E/AndroidRuntime(5401):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-01 04:51:22.903: E/AndroidRuntime(5401):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
06-01 04:51:22.903: E/AndroidRuntime(5401):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
06-01 04:51:22.903: E/AndroidRuntime(5401):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
06-01 04:51:22.903: E/AndroidRuntime(5401):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-01 04:51:22.903: E/AndroidRuntime(5401): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
06-01 04:51:22.903: E/AndroidRuntime(5401):     at com.example.fatwallet.Create_adds_Activity.onActivityResult(Create_adds_Activity.java:109)
06-01 04:51:22.903: E/AndroidRuntime(5401):     at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:3890)
06-01 04:51:22.903: E/AndroidRuntime(5401):     at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3511)
06-01 04:51:22.903: E/AndroidRuntime(5401):     ... 11 more
```

Comment: If your getting the force close error, could you please post the LogCat output? This will allow us to check exactly what is making the app crash.

Comment: What do you mean "forces close"? Is this the dreaded "App is Not Responding" message?

Comment: Can you add it as an edit to your question please, instead of in the comments :) thanks. Also, which line is line 109?

Comment: ok and this is  109 line

06-01 04:51:22.903: E/AndroidRuntime(5401):  at com.example.fatwallet.Create_adds_Activity.onActivityResult(Create_adds_Activity.java:109)

Comment: No, which line is line 109 in the java file

Comment: imageView.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath));

Comment: That means that your imageView is probably null. Is imageView10 in the same XML file as your activity?

Comment: no Imageview 10 is located in another activity/xml

Comment: That is the reason why-- because it is in another XML file, it will return null.

Comment: so now what can i do:-(

Comment: Assuming that you want to launch a new activity, and then show the picture in the new Activity, I would just pass the filePath to the new activity (using `intent.putExtra()`), and let the new activity load the image / set the image view.

Comment: sorry i did not understand ur answer can u explain me in detail

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are getting an "App is not responding" or ANR error. This means that you are doing too much work on the UI thread. To solve the problem, you need to create a new thread or use AsyncTask to do the image loading.